# DrawerActions.toggleDrawer() from Parent Navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

I have a nested navigator structure as follows - the Parent element is a Stack Navigator with a Drawer nested inside. I need to toggle the drawer open from a button in the Stack Navigator.

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
function DrawerNav() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Main"
          component={HomeScreen}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Details"
          component={DetailsScreen}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="About"
          component={AboutScreen}
        />
    </Drawer.Navigator
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
             initialRouteName="DrawerNav"
        >
            <Stack.Screen
                name="DrawerNav"
                component={DrawerNav}
                options={{
                   headerLeft: () => (
                      <Icon
                         style={{ padding: 10 }}
                         name="menu"
                         size={30}
                         color="#900"
                         onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
                     />
                  ),
                }}
            />
        </Stack.Navigator>
     </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

The current onpress in the Stack Navigator is the closest I got to something that should work to toggle the child drawer. However, adding

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
```

Into the App() function creates the following error

```
Error: Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator?\\
```

In summation, I need to toggle the drawer navigation though a button in its parent. It is clear how to pass navigation actions to children but I am having a difficult time doing it the other way.

Answer (score 3):

DrawerActions must be imported, so

```
import { NavigationContainer, DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

should be in your imports, other than that,

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
```

does the trick.

I know this is an old topic, but I thought I would offer some clarification.
Read up on Drawer Actions -> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-actions/

Answer (score 1):

In `options` you need to extract the navigation argument:

```
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
    function DrawerNav() {
      return (
          <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
              <Drawer.Screen
                 name="Main"
                 component={HomeScreen}
               />
               <Drawer.Screen
                 name="Details"
                 component={DetailsScreen}
               />
               <Drawer.Screen
                 name="About"
                 component={AboutScreen}
                />
         </Drawer.Navigator
     );
    }

    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
           <Stack.Navigator
              initialRouteName="DrawerNav"
           >
            <Stack.Screen
              name="DrawerNav"
              component={DrawerNav}
              options={({ navigation }) => ({
                 headerLeft: () => (
                  <Icon
                     style={{ padding: 10 }}
                     name="menu"
                     size={30}
                     color="#900"
                     onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
                  />
                 ),
              })}
             />
          </Stack.Navigator>
       </NavigationContainer>
     );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this out, i was stuck on the same issue and this worked for me :**

```
   <Stack.Screen
            name="screen name"
            component={ScreenComponent}
            options={({ navigation }) => ({ 
              headerRight: (props) => {
                return <Button onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer() }} />
              }
            })}
          />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can toggle Drawer by Button click using the following code-

`onPress={() => this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}`

`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work when the drawer navigation is nested inside the element where the onPress is

Answer (score -1):

`options` can take a function and provide arguments for you, one of which is `navigation`. Here's the code:

```
options={({navigation}) => {
               headerLeft: () => (
                  <Icon
                     style={{ padding: 10 }}
                     name="menu"
                     size={30}
                     color="#900"
                     onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
                 />
              ),
            }}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately adding that argument in the way you describe gives a syntax error